# ListView shows loads image for item out of view when no image has been set for the item

Tags: android

my ListView seems to be working correctly when the images loaded can be viewed on the screen. but when i add a new item with no image, and the item is out of view, the ListView keeps loading an image for it. i am using a custom arrayadapter.

```
 int resource;
        private RecipeClasses mRecipeClass;
        private Recipe mRecipe;
        private Context context;
        Uri path;

    public RecipeAdapter(Context context, int _resource, List<Recipebag> items)
    {
        super(context, _resource, items);
        resource = _resource;
        mRecipeClass = new RecipeClasses(context);
        this.context = context;
        mRecipe = new Recipe(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        LinearLayout newView;
        Recipebag item = getItem(position);
        long id = item.getRecId();
        mRecipeClass.open();
        Cursor recipe = mRecipe.setCursorToRecipe(id);
        String name = recipe.getString(recipe.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RecipeClasses.Recipe.RECIPE_NAME));
        String image = recipe.getString(recipe.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RecipeClasses.Recipe.RECIPE_IMAGE));
        mRecipeClass.close();
        String newId = String.valueOf(id);
        if(image== null)
        {
            image = " ";
        }
        else
        {
             path = Uri.parse(image);
        }

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            // Inflate a new view if this is not an update.
            newView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater li;
            li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
            li.inflate(resource, newView, true);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise we’ll update the existing View
            newView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        TextView recipe_txt = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.txt_recipe_row);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_recipe);
        if(new File(image).exists())
        {
        ImageResizer img_W = new ImageResizer(context, img.getMeasuredWidth(), img.getMeasuredHeight());
        img_W.loadImage(image, img);
        }
        else if(image!= " ")

        {
            ImageResizer img_W = new ImageResizer(context, img.getMeasuredWidth(), img.getMeasuredHeight());
            img_W.loadImage(path, img);
            img.setImageURI(path);
        }
        if (recipe_txt != null)
        {
            recipe_txt.setText(name);
        }
        return newView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near as I can tell, you are never clearing the content of your `ImageView` in `getView()`. Hence, when the row is recycled, it will already have an image. You need to handle the case where you have no image in `getView()` -- try `setImageDrawable(null)` or something.

Comment: wow...it worked thanks man, just need to show a default image instead

Answer (score 0):

You should just cater for the no image case i.e. display a default image for the time being until you want to update the recipe image.

try this

```
if(image != null)
{ 
   icon.setImageBitmap(image); 
    return; 
}
```

Icon will be the ImageView

The image you set will be your default image(R.id.default) if its in your project resources
or 
Copy the systems resources image that you want into your project and call it from there.